# How to save files to Parquet with Spark so that header is ready/available during reads?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am reading data using Spark ('2.4.3' version) from S3 location (folder) where files are saved as `csv.gz`.

First line is a header.

If I just read files as `df = spark.read.csv("s3://myfolder")` and save as `df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(write_folder)` -> files are written as Parquet files but when reading them back to some DF - columns are not identified by default (e.g. `df.columns` shows `_c0, _c1...`).

What is the proper way to save file to Parquet so that column names are ready when reading parquet files later?

I am trying to avoid infer schema (or any other gymnastics) during reading from parquet if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the code as follows:

```
df = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("s3://myfolder")
df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(write_folder)
```

The reason you are not getting column names is because Spark is reading your header row as same as the other rows containing the data.
You should now be able to see your column names in the parquet files

Following are some options you can use when working with CSV data:

**Read CSV files**

**path:** location of files. Accepts standard Hadoop globbing expressions. To read a directory of CSV files, specify a directory.
header: when set to true, the first line of files name columns and are not included in data. All types are assumed to be string. Default value is false.

**sep:** the column delimiter. By default ,, but can be set to any character.

**quote:** the quote character. By default ", but can be set to any character. Delimiters inside quotes are ignored.
escape: the escape character. By default \, but can be set to any character. Escaped quote characters are ignored.
parserLib: by default is commons. Can be set to univocity to use that library for CSV parsing.

**mode:** the parsing mode. By default it is PERMISSIVE. Possible values are:
PERMISSIVE: try to parse all lines: nulls are inserted for missing tokens and extra tokens are ignored.

**DROPMALFORMED:** drop lines that have fewer or more tokens than expected or tokens which do not match the schema.

**FAILFAST:** abort with a RuntimeException if any malformed line is encountered.

**charset:** the character set. By default UTF-8, but can be set to other valid charset names.

**inferSchema:** automatically infer column types. It requires one extra pass over the data and is false by default.

**comment:** skip lines beginning with this character. Default is #. Disable comments by setting this to null.

**nullValue:** string that indicates a null value, any fields matching this string will be set as nulls in the DataFrame.

**dateFormat:** string that indicates the date format to use when reading dates or timestamps. Custom date formats follow the formats at java.text.SimpleDateFormat. This applies to both DateType and TimestampType. By default it is null, which means try to parse times and date by java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf() and java.sql.Date.valueOf().

**Write CSV files to storage:(if ever required)**

**path:** location of files.

**header:** when set to true, the header (from the schema in the DataFrame) is written at the first line.

**sep:** the column delimiter. By default ,, but can be set to any character.

**quote:** the quote character. By default ", but can be set to any character. This is written according to quoteMode.

**escape:** the escape character. By default \, but can be set to any character. Escaped quote characters are written.

**nullValue:** string that indicates a null value, nulls in the DataFrame will be written as this string.

**dateFormat:** string that indicates the date format to use writing dates or timestamps. Custom date formats follow the formats at java.text.SimpleDateFormat. This applies to both DateType and TimestampType. If no dateFormat is specified, then yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S.

**codec:** compression codec to use when saving. Should be the fully qualified name of a class implementing org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec or one of case-insensitive short names (bzip2, gzip, lz4, and snappy). Defaults to no compression.

**quoteMode:** when to quote fields (ALL, MINIMAL (default), NON_NUMERIC, NONE)

Comment: Thanks! Easy fix :)

Comment: header with parquet? csv and parquet?

Comment: For a normal comma delimited csv, I had to do `spark.read.option("header", "true").option("sep", ",").option("delimeter",",").csv(<the path>)`, but it's working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you write the dataframe you should add an extra option in order to also write the header:

```
df.write.option("header", "true").mode("overwrite").parquet(write_folder)
```